# can I develop react-native app inside docker image

Tags: macos, docker, react-native

My development machine is MacBook Pro, on which I'm trying to create a docker image based on Ubuntu 16.04 for developing React-Native apps. I'm aware I can install react native, android, cli etc directly on Mac but I'm trying to avoid, as docker is better for porting code easily using git CI/CD pipeline as well as maintaining packages etc versions.

I couldn't find any decent workable solution, few URLs that I referred are given below for your reference.

1. https://medium.com/@hmajid2301/running-expo-react-native-in-docker-ff9c4f2a4388
2. https://github.com/react-native-community/docker-android/blob/master/Dockerfile
3. https://github.com/symbiote/docker-project/blob/master/node/Dockerfile

My Dockerfile is as following at the moment, its building the image but Expo app doesn't seem to open my react native app runing.

```
FROM node:8.11

RUN npm install -g grunt-cli \
    && npm install -g brunch \
    && npm install -g bower \
    && npm install -g yarn \
    && npm install -g create-react-native-app \
    && npm install -g react-native-cli \ 
    && npm install -g expo-cli 
EXPORT 3000 19000 19001

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Has anyone successfully setup Docker image for development of react native mobile apps? If yes, please share your knowledge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I know its an old post but might help some one else.

I managed to run expo-cli in a docker image and do remote development using VS Code. Wrote a blog post explaining the work flow. Can check the post [here](https://sonyarouje.com/2019/08/02/expo-react-native-development-in-docker/).

All the docker files are pushed to [git](https://github.com/sonyarouje/expo-docker).

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this and solved your problem. First, you need to replace EXPORT with EXPOSE. Secondly, you need to to open the ports used by expo at the docker cmd you use to invoke your docker machine using

....  -p 3000:3000 -p 19000:19000 -p 19001:19001 -p 19002:19002  ...

Lastly, run your app using npm start like at:

```
expo init AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject
npm start # you can also use: expo start
```

Now from Expo search for this app using your computer ipaddress and the 19000 port like at:

```
exp://<ipaddress>:19000
```

and voila!!

Remember: YOU will need node 10+ to use this option

Answer (score 0):

I am very confident that what you are trying to do is possible.  Without having done it myself, I can not say 100% confidence,

However, your Dockerfile is clearly wrong.  I do not know what the correct way would be.  That is your work.

I think that somehow you need to get the react-native code that you are writing into the container.  For example you could:

- use a COPY command in the Dockerfile;
- or bind mount it at runtime (which you might be doing); or
- there are a lot of other ways to get the code into the container.

Imagine you were working on an ubuntu machine.  You just installed all the software, checked out the source code, did any necessary compilation.  Your react-native app is ready to be used.  You type "/usr/bin/xyx a b c" into the shell and the magic happens.  This suggests that your `CMD` command should be "/usr/bin/xyz a b c".

Comment: hi emory, thanks.
I'm aware that I'm missing something with above Dockerfile steps, hence trying to see if anyone has achieved this task before. My image is building fine, after that I use "docker run -it docker-image-tag", I can connect to the image and after that I'm able to create a blank app, the problem pops when I scan QR code in Expo app on my mobile, it says couldn't load app.